# Position div above theme in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I'm writing a news ticker style plugin. I'm having trouble positioning the banner above the theme headers. Most themes position their header using top: 0px; I'm not sure how to position my div above these headers or push the headers down. Adding padding / margin to the body doesn't help.

Comment: can you post you code?

Answer (score 0):

Would be nice to see your code but from what I can guess using

```
body {
  position:relative;
  top:100px;
}
```

should work in most cases.